# Convert a VirtualBox VM into main OS

Tags: virtualbox, arch-linux

I have an old Vostro 1500 which has a rare wifi card, so it isn't included in the default firmware, and a broken Ethernet port and I want to install Arch Linux on it.

That of course is practically impossible because you need an ethernet connection to even install the wifi drivers that are needed.

Anyway, I currently have elementaryOS Luna installed, which has allowed me to use a USB drive to download the drivers in another computer and install the firmware for the wifi card manually. I have a working laptop with internet.

However I definitely miss Arch Linux and I can't be as efficient as I want with this OS.

So, the idea I came up with to be able to install Arch Linux on this laptop even though I don't have Ethernet is the following:

- Install VirtualBox or similar in current OS and make a working Arch Linux virtual box.
- Put that VirtualBox in a USB or something of the sort (that has a working portable OS running).
- Boot from the USB and make the virtual box take over the laptop's hard drive.

So that's the idea I had. I don't know if it's possible, I really hope it is.

Any help on what to do to on that last step is appreciated as I have no idea myself. :)

Comment: Why not just install a base Arch Linux from CD/DVD/USB, then copy over the driver you need via USB?  I'm also confused by your use of firmware and driver - you seem to use the two terms interchangeably, when they technically refer to very different things?  And according to [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_Vostro_1500) the default wifi on that is Intel, which is not "rare" by any stretch of the imagination . . . nor are the Dell wireless cards rare.

Comment: Make your life easier, go [spend $15 on a new USB network adapter](http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=sr_aj?node=13983791&ajr=0) and try to get it working in the notebook.  ;)

Comment: @ernie It is a `Broadcom Corporation BCM4312`. Also the reason I can't put the driver on a USB is because, AFAIK, you also need to do some mumbo jumbo to open USB drives inside Arch Linux. It was that way last time I tried.

Comment: @techie007 That's a good idea... I may do that if I can't figure it out. :)

Comment: You do not need to do this at all: according to Linux Wireless, http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43, your card is fully supported by b43, the wonderful open source driver, which has been in-kernel for many years now (forgot how many). You can get a list of necessary firmware from the command modinfo b43, copy it to a USB stick  and then to the new system.

Comment: I do not think so. What do you mean? You only need to install it once.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I re-read your comment now and what I said was incorrect. I still need to access the stuff through a USB drive, which IIRC is a PITA. At least it was last time I tried... And if I wipe the hard drive to install an OS I need to do it again.

Comment: I'd boot off a modern Arch Linux live CD, and check your assumption about the USB drive support.  Stock kernel should support USB drives auto-magically out of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end because of difficulties I just installed ArchBang with the normal process and added the B43 stuff through a USB.

Thank you for your answers and suggestions but in the end I didn't really use any of them. :/

Answer (score 1):

I was building couple of arch distros on virtual box and then I was dd-ing them directly into (earlier prepared) partitions on VPS's. This approach is quite simple however I would not be so sure about your old hardware...

Anyway - this link might be worth checking out:
https://library.linode.com/migration/ssh-copy

This article is talking about dd-ing over ssh but I'm sure if you just copy your image into USB and then boot your old machine with live CD/USB you should be able to dd it to your HDD.

Comment: Cool. I'll be looking into that. Thank you! :)

Comment: I wanted to put that into comment but could not due to low rank :-)